# syntax error near unexpected token `unset'

Tags: bash

I'm trying to source my `~/.bashrc` file and I get the following error

```
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 57: syntax error near unexpected token `unset'
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 57: `fi unset color_prompt force_color_prompt'
```

how can I fix it? is it a typo?

here's my entire `.bashrc` file

```
  GNU nano 6.2                         /home/arnle/.bashrc                                   
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells. see 
# /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc) for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history. See bash(1) 
# for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000 HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary, update the values of 
# LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will match all files 
# and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then debian_chroot=$(cat 
    /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned off by 
# default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window should be on the 
# output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 
    >&/dev/null; then

         # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48 (ISO/IEC-6429). 
        # (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such a case would tend to 
        # support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes else
        color_prompt=
    fi fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then 
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\>
    '
else PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b 
    ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)" alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto' alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto' alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto' alias 
    egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors export 
#GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF' alias la='ls -A' alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so: sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo 
error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'



# Alias definitions. You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like 
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly. See 
# /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable this, if it's 
# already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/arnle/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> 
/dev/null)" if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup" else
    if [ -f "/home/arnle/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/arnle/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" else
        export PATH="/home/arnle/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi fi unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" eval "$(pyenv 
init --path)" export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" 
eval "$(pyenv init --path)" eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

# >>> juliaup initialize >>>

# !! Contents within this block are managed by juliaup !!

case ":$PATH:" in *:/home/arnle/.juliaup/bin:*)
        ;;

    *) export PATH=/home/arnle/.juliaup/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
        ;;
esac

# <<< juliaup initialize <<<

export PATH="$PATH:/home/arnle/julia-1.9.0-beta4/bin"
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then 
>     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\>
>     '
> else PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
> fi unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
> ```

Stacking more than one `fi` without a semicolon/newline in between is allowed (as are things like `fi esac } done`), but you can't put a regular command after `fi` without the semicolon or a newline in between.

The way the main branch of the conditional is on a separate line from the `if`, but the `else` branch is stacked with the `else` looks a bit odd, and almost like the newline disappear e.g. when copypasting the code from some tool that didn't keep the formatting properly intact.

I would format that with a more symmetrical indentation, and incidentally, in Bash you can insert the newline with e.g. `$'\n'` without needing to use a hard newline in the quoted string. So:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then 
    PS1='...\[\033[01;34m\]\>'$'\n'
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

You have others like that too, `fi fi unset __conda_setup` and `fi export ...` at least.

Here,

> ```
> __conda_setup="$(...)" if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
> ```

The `then` keyword is in error, since the `if` isn't recognized as a keyword in the middle of the line. (Instead it would be the name of a regular command here, probably giving a confusing "command not found" error.) You can't put assignments or redirections before a compound command, like you can do with simple commands, so that one needs a newline too. That means the assigned value will be effective for the rest of the script, not just for the command (like with `var=foobar some command`). But then there's that `unset` later there, so the newlines appear to be missing in error.

Except that, your code actually reads like this, with a newline after the `2>`:

> ```
> __conda_setup="$('.../conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> 
> /dev/null)" if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
> ```

That's a syntax error of its own, the filename after the redirection has to come on the same line. (Which is unlike e.g.  `|` or `&&`, which you can just drop at the end of a line, and the next command works as part of the pipeline or list as if the newline wasn't there.)